# TypeError: ModelBase object got multiple values for keyword argument Django

Tags: django

Got an error - Exception Value: ModelBase object got multiple values for keyword argument `voucher`. Trying to insert two rows with these two dictionaries.

```
if form.is_valid():
    debit_tr ={
        'voucher': newvoucher,
        'descirption': 'Purchase Order: '+ self.request.POST.get('purchase_id'),
        'debit':self.request.POST.get('total_amount'),
        'account':self.request.POST.get('debit_account')
    }
    credit_tr ={
        'voucher': newvoucher,
        'descirption': 'Purchase Order: '+ self.request.POST.get('purchase_id'),
        'credit':self.request.POST.get('paid_amount'),
        'account':self.request.POST.get('credit_account')
    }
    j = Journal(**debit_tr, **credit_tr)
    j.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact with this line :

> j = Journal(**debit_tr, **credit_tr)

You are trying to put both dictionnaries into a single entry.
Since you have 1 `voucher` field in each dictionnary, it raises this error.

It will do the same with `descirption` and `account`.

You should try to save 2 different objects.

```py
debit_tr ={
    'voucher': newvoucher,
    'descirption': 'Purchase Order: '+ self.request.POST.get('purchase_id'),
    'debit':self.request.POST.get('total_amount'),
    'account':self.request.POST.get('debit_account')
}
debit = Journal(**debit_tr)
debit.save()
credit_tr ={
    'voucher': newvoucher,
    'descirption': 'Purchase Order: '+ self.request.POST.get('purchase_id'),
    'credit':self.request.POST.get('paid_amount'),
    'account':self.request.POST.get('credit_account')
}
credit = Journal(**credit_tr)
credit.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create two separate Journal instances, save two different objects:

```
debit_tr ={
    'voucher': newvoucher,
    'descirption': 'Purchase Order: '+ self.request.POST.get('purchase_id'),
    'debit':self.request.POST.get('total_amount'),
    'account':self.request.POST.get('debit_account')
}
j1 = Journal(**debit_tr)
j1.save()
credit_tr ={
    'voucher': newvoucher,
    'descirption': 'Purchase Order: '+ self.request.POST.get('purchase_id'),
    'credit':self.request.POST.get('paid_amount'),
    'account':self.request.POST.get('credit_account')
}
j2 = Journal(**credit_tr)
j2.save()
```